# Getting 404 using Backload

Tags: asp.net-mvc, backload

I am using ASP.NET MVC 5.1 and Backload 1.9.3 and I am getting 404 in `/Backload/UploadHandler`. I have referenced the assembly but seems it is not being loaded.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with Backload recently and the problem ended up being with WebDAV intercepting requests that were intended for Backload. Removing WebDAV in the web.config file worked for me. I followed these instructions: http://bradkingsley.com/putpostdelete-verb-errors-on-site/

Hope this helps.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The problem has nothing to do with MVC 5.1. It's a WebDAV issue. The examples on GitHub also disable WebDAV.